# Vba collection set and retrieve value from collection within custom function

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying loop over a cell range (single column) that contains names and codes containing the string "cgl".

I can loop over the range and identify the cells but i was trying to use a collection to store the name and the row number so i can return it. But i am  not setting the value correctly and probably not retrieving the value correctly (the msg box command does not work after this point). I am using excel 2007.

I followed examples found in other q's, online help, but what is the correct way to use collection?

```
Function DHNameRows(rng As Range, name)
' eg name = david

    Dim item As Range
    Dim staff As Collection
    Set staff = New Collection

    For Each item In rng
        found = InStr(item.Value, "CGL")
        If found = 0 Then
            'item value should equal david
            MsgBox item.Value
            staff.Add item.Value, item.Row
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox staff.item(name)
    DHNameRows = staff.item(name)

End Function
```

Comment: [Check this out](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm) which I think got what you need.

Comment: `staff.item(name)` What are you expecting this to return? The row number?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett yes the row number - name should equal to item.Value set in the loop

Comment: Collection keys are write-only. Once they're written in the collection, you can't retrieve them like you're trying to do. Try a Dictionary object instead.